# SharePoint 2010 html rich text editor styles menu in ribbon not showing up

Tags: sharepoint

Guys i have a serious problem, like in the image below , the styles menu is not showing for html rich editor in sharepoint 2010, i included the *.css file and the PrefixStyleSheet

any help ?  :(

[image: Styles menu is not showing]

Comment: Please use sharepoint.stackexchange.com for non-programming related questions. You will also need to provide some more information. Your whole styles look messed up. Did you make any changes? Look at the "Paragrah" and "Font" texts they seem to be beneath the ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

Did yor read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551040.aspx and especially the first section which specifies how to set the PrefixStyleSheet-property of the RTE-control? If you then add css-classes with the specified stylesheet-prefix in your css, they should show up in the Styles or Markup Styles section depending on the context of the editing.
Have you done the above steps?

If you set PrefixStyleSheet to, for example "Test", your css should look like this to have a H1 show up in the Markup Styles section:

```
H1.TestElement-H1
{
    -ms-name: "Heading 1";
}
```

and markup:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="Content" PrefixStyleSheet="Test" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" runat="server" />
```

Comment: i've done this, but the problem is that the menu doesn't show up even for default styles, not custom styles, any help ?

Comment: The hard part about this type of customization is that it is completely silent when it fails, no traces in log or anything.. :( Can you post how you declare your RichHtmlFieldControl and your css so we can help you look through it?

Comment: <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="Content" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" runat="server" />

Comment: You need to add the PrefixStyleSheet-property to declaration. I have added this to my above example.

Comment: i think the default prefix is ms-rte, i have added your code but still the same problem which is, the styles menu doesn't show even with the default styles, any help ?

Comment: Sorry man, out of ideas. If I were you, I would try and create a new SiteCollection using standard publishing template. Then I would add my css to it and see if it works. If it does, I'd start removing stuff from my custom site, until I found what breaks it.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Get a copy of corev4.css and do a search for ms-rte. Keep searching untill you get to a bit that looks like this:

```
H1.ms-rteElement-H1 {
    -ms-name: "Heading 1"
}
.ms-rteElement-H1 {
    FONT-SIZE: 2em; FONT-WEIGHT: normal
}
```

Use the supplied values to build your own styles and Markups.

Assuming your prefix is `PrefixStyleSheet="myPrefex"`

Markup Styles seem to require 2 css entries each. So if you wanted a markup style called "HEADING ONE!!!FTW" that was 2em bold you would have:

```
H1.myPrefexElement-H1 {
    -ms-name: "HEADING ONE!!!FTW";
}
.myPrefexElement-H1 {
    FONT-SIZE: 2em; FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}
```

Markup styles are applied to existing HTML tags, so it appears the logic behind rolling your own is to overload the HTML tag with your own class name and give it a label, then flesh out your class with the actual css goodness.

Items in the STYLES drop down seem to only require a single line:

```
.myPrefexStyle-Bold {
    -ms-name: "Bold Bits";
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

But besure to include the -ms-name attribute as this determines the text that appears in the drop down (If you dont have this attribute you end up with blanks)

PS: Dont forget to include your own css stylesheet in the master or layout or page. I ended up putting in my master page with:     `<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/MyCustomMarkup.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>`

*[offtopic]Ive only just started with sharepoint, but boy is it a dogs breakfast behind the scenes! The horror, the horror![/offtopic]*

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom style prefix you must set both `PrefixStyleSheet` and `Stylesheet` property:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField AllowFontsMenu="True" FieldName="Page Content" runat="server" PrefixStyleSheet="custom-rte" Stylesheet="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/custom_rte.css %>"/>
```

Remember that doing this you will overwrite all dropdowns, colors and other options in RTE, so if you want to only change the Styles dropdown you still must to copy all the default rules.